# Как вернуть тип переменной и любого другого элемента программы в с++?

Tags: c++, типы-данных

Есть такой примитивный код.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

template<typename T> void Fun(T a[]) //здесь я использую шаблон чтобы 
{                            //программа сама определила какой тип
}                          //массива будет передан в функцию

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    double mas[6]={1,2,3,4,5,6},//
    Fun(reinterpret_cast <double*>(mas));
    // здесь вызывается функция и если массив не одномерный как в моём случае
    //требуется запись reinterpret_cast и указание типа массива с которым будем 
    //работать функция
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Значит вопрос в следующем: как сделать так чтобы в этом месте reinterpret_cast  можно было использовать механизм, который определит тип массива, так как в разработке предполагается работа со всеми типами массивов. которые существуют в природе начиная от int и заканчивая string? Нужно создать универсальный модуль определяющий тип массива. Может кто-нибудь помочь решить эту головоломку?

Comment: Встроенной реализации рефлексии в `C++` нет как таковой, только сторонние (как правило не без глюков) библиотеки. Или пытаться создать код огромного размера с помощью `constexpr` например https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constexpr

Comment: Типичная XY проблема.  Никакого `reinterpret_cast` там быть не должно. Если ваша функция не работает правильно "если массив не одномерный", значит надо писать функцию по-другому, так, чтобы она работала, а не заниматься `reinterpret_cast`-ингом.

Comment: Дело в том что передаваться туда будут массивы разных типов, а многомерные массивы конвертируются в одномерные и без записи reinterpret_cast <double*> работать функция не хочет, т.к. указываешь количество столбцов и строк, информацию брал из этого форума, ссылка не влазит.

Comment: #include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

template<typename T>
void function(T a)
{}

int main()
{
    double mas1[2][2]={{1,4},{2,6}};
    function(reinterpret_cast <double*>(mas1));
}

Comment: Не до конца понятно, что вы хотите сделать. Ну допустим мы можем определить тип массива. Что дальше? Ограниченно, это, кстати, сделать можно. К примеру, вызывать разные перегрузки функции в зависимости от типа или того, является ли функция массивом массивов. reinterpret_cast нужно использовать с максимальной осторожностью, обычно в момент, когда ты хочешь максимально абстрагироваться от того, с каким типом разотаешь и обратно. К примеру при записи бинарного представления структуры в файл/сокет и считывания обратно.

Answer (score 0):

Что-то подобное Вам подойдет?

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

template<typename T>
void function(T a)
{
    //some important stuff
}

int main()
{
    double mas[6] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6 };
    function(mas);
}
```